# merging data in R

Tags: r, merge

I have a data set A

```
paper_id author_id
  1       521630
  1       1611750
  2       9
  3       627950
  4       1456512
  8       15
  ........
```

and a data set B

```
author_id    author_name        author_affiliation
    9       Ernest Jordan            Cambridge                                                    
    14         K. MORIBE               NA                                                 
    15     D. Jakominich               NA                                                 
    25     William H. Nailon                                                                
    37     P. B. Littlewood    Cavendish Laboratory|Cambridge University 
    ........
```

I want to merge these two data sets in such a way so that merging is done through author_id but result should be seen like:

```
paper id    author_id        author_name     author_affiliation
  2            9             Ernest Jordan     Cambridge
  8            15            D. Jakominich       NA
```

That is I want to have data in the order by paper_id only and merging is performed on the author_id, such that all the paper_id order doesnt get disturbed.

From what I am doing is:

```
b<-merge(A,B,by="author_id")
```

and I am getting. In this the paper_id is getting disturbed

```
 author_id paper_id       author_name      author_affiliation
     9     1468598       Ernest Jordan       cambridge
     9     1682105       Ernest Jordan       cambridge
```

and then I have to sort this output by sorting through paper_id column.Its a very inefficient way.

How could this be done.

Thanks

Comment: what is inefficient? Sorting the data after a merge? I'm not sure what your problem with the current output is

Comment: You can reorder the data: `b[order(b$paper_id), ]`.

Comment: ok thanks.I just wanted to know if there's a better way

Comment: I don't see (below) that you need to reorder the results at all. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You can specify the argument `sort=FALSE` to `merge` and the resulting data will then not be sorted based on the `by` column(s). However, the rows will be "in an unspecified order." See the `Value` section of the help page for `merge` for more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can consider non-`base` alternatives, then you may try the `plyr` equivalent of `merge`: `join`. From "Details" in `?join`: `Unlike merge, preserves the order of x no matter what join type is used.`. Also the order of columns is preserved.

```
library(plyr)
join(A, B, type = "inner")
# Joining by: author_id
#   paper_id author_id  author_name author_affiliation
# 1        2         9 ErnestJordan          Cambridge
# 2        8        15   Jakominich               <NA>
```

`inner_join` in `dplyr` is similar. However, while the order of columns in `x` is kept, the columns in `y` seem to be sorted alphabetically:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(x = A, y = B)
# Joining by: "author_id"
#   paper_id author_id author_affiliation  author_name
# 1        2         9          Cambridge ErnestJordan
# 2        8        15               <NA>   Jakominich
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want.

```
b <-merge(A,B,by="author_id", sort=F)
b <- b[,c(2,1,3,4)]
```

You can turn off sorting on the `by=...` columns with `sort=F`, but `merge(...)` will always make the sort columns the first columns of the result. The last line of code just reverses columns 1 and 2.

**EDIT** (Response to @BrianDiggs comment)

@BrianDiggs is correct that, while `sort=F` will not force a sort on the `by=...` column, it does not guarantee the original sort order in `A`. If efficiency is a big concern, then consider the `data.table` package, which was built for this:

```
# create an example
A <- data.frame(paper_id=1:10000, author_id=rev(LETTERS[1:4]))
B <- data.frame(author_id=LETTERS[1:4],
                author_name=c("Davies","Hawking","Carlyle","Higgs"),
                author_affiliation=c("Oxford","Cambridge","UCL","Edinburgh"),
                stringsAsFactors=F)

library(data.table)
A <- data.table(A,key="author_id")
B <- data.table(B,key="author_id")
A[B,c("author_name","author_affiliation"):=list(author_name,author_affiliation)]
setkey(A,paper_id)
head(A)
#    paper_id author_id author_name author_affiliation
# 1:        1         D       Higgs          Edinburgh
# 2:        2         C     Carlyle                UCL
# 3:        3         B     Hawking          Cambridge
# 4:        4         A      Davies             Oxford
# 5:        5         D       Higgs          Edinburgh
# 6:        6         C     Carlyle                UCL
```

Unlike `sort(...)`, setting a key in a data table sorts "by reference" using a radix algorithm. Sorting by reference means that the rows are rearranged in memory instead of copying the whole table into a new table. As a result, sorting data tables is extremely fast and memory efficient.

Also, the use of `A[B,...]` to do the merge is much faster than merging two data frames. In addition, this process *appends* the new columns to A (rather than creating a copy of A as with `merge(...)`.

Comment: Beware that `sort=FALSE` does not guarantee the order of `b` to be the same as `A` (or `B`); it is documented that the order is unspecified. Thus you would still need a `b<-b[order(b$paper_id),]` to ensure that ordering.

Comment: @BrianDiggs - You're right. It did seem to work in OP's case though. See edits.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment*

I do get what you want:

```
A <- read.table(text="paper_id author_id
1       521630
1       1611750
2       9
3       627950
4       1456512
8       15", header=T)

B <- read.table(text="author_id  author_name author_affiliation
9       Ernest_Jordan            Cambridge
14         K._MORIBE               NA
15     D._Jakominich               NA
25     William_H._Nailon           NA
37     P._B._Littlewood    Cavendish_Laboratory|Cambridge_University", 
header=T)

b <- merge(A, B, by="author_id")
b
#   author_id paper_id   author_name author_affiliation
# 1         9        2 Ernest_Jordan          Cambridge
# 2        15        8 D._Jakominich               <NA>
```

Can you clarify your problem?